# adding dynamic rows to google chart

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

I'm using google Line chart for my college project, here i want to add rows dynamically based on the user selection from database, addRow() function is used to add a row but i want it to be add by looping. someone can help me?

Here is my code:

```
var rowArray1 = [];
var rowArray2 = [];
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
$row=mysql_fetch_array($rows);
echo "rowArray1.push('". $row['a'] ."')";
echo "rowArray2.push(". $row['b'].")";

array_push($rowArray,"'".$row['a']."',".$row['b']);
} 
?>


for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
   data.addRow( [rowArray1[i], rowArray2[i]] );
}
```

it's not working properly... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. it's very simple way. when i asked this question, i was just a beginner so i dont know how to do it. now i got the answer.

I just included the PHP scripts inside the javascript code like this,

```
<script>
// Google chart codes....

<?php
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($rows);
  foreach($row as $data) {
    echo "data.addRow( $data['a'] , $data['b'] );";  
  } 
?>

// Google chart codes....
</script>
```

It's worked fine... :)